# Error 404 on OWIN self-hosted WebAPI with load balancer and Ok with IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, owin, load-balancing

I have this scenerario:

- I have a load balancer with a public URI. It has a concrete port redirected to another machine called 'Frontal'. In the future there will be more machines 'Frontal2', 'Frontal3' and so on.
- In that 'Frontal' machine, I have an OWIN self-hosted WebAPI service listening to that port.
- If I send an HTTP request to the service from the 'Frontal' machine using localhost:port/api/... and the Host header = 'Frontal:port' it runs properly and I get a 200 response.
- If I send the same HTTP request from other machines out the load balancer, using the name of the 'load balancer:port' in the Host header, I get a 404 error as a result.
- If I send the same HTTP request from other machines out the load balancer, using the 'Frontal:port' Host header, It returns a 200 response correctly.
- But if I stop that service, and active the same WebAPI as an application into an IIS in the same 'Frontal' machine, and then I send a request wiht 'load balancer:port' Host header to the balancer, the WebAPI returns a 200 response correctly.

That is: Using the Self-hosted I can't access the service if I do not explicitily sets the Host header to the name of the 'Frontal', when the correct is set this header to the name of the public load balancer. But if I install the WebAPI into an IIS, it runs correctly.

I think I need to configure something in the OWIN service, but I don't know what it can be. Can you help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? Running into the same issue and cannot find anything that matches my scenario as close as this on the internet